# What happens when one aggregates without the 'group by' clause?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I was wondering why this SQL script

```
SELECT category, avg(valuation)
FROM startups
group by 1;
```

Gives me the same output like this one:

```
SELECT category, valuation
FROM startups
group by 1;
```

And why is it possible to group by without any aggregation clause...

Comment: Note that the second statement is invalid standard SQL and will be rejected by most DBMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A statement like:

```
SELECT category, valuation
FROM startups
group by 1;
```

is allowed in SQLite.
In this case `valuation` is called a *"bare"* column (you can find more here: [2. Simple Select Processing](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#simple_select_processing)).
The result that you get for this column is **undefined**, meaning it can be any of the values of `valuation` of the `category`.

I highly doubt that you get the same results as:

```
SELECT category, avg(valuation)
FROM startups
group by 1;
```

which is a valid SQL statement and returns the average of `valuation` for each `category`.
Unless all the `valuation`s for each `category` are the same then the similarity in the results is coincidental.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d14f6eb01020a032b482269a7b1bbff1).